# Paste into SQL Server table via Management Studio 2005 and keep line endings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms, paste, line-endings

I cannot get this to work. I have opened a SQL Server Express table in SQL Server Management Studio 2005. When I try to paste a multiline text snippet into an NTEXT field it gets truncated to only include the first line.

In Access these kind of things works, what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite it as an UPDATE or INSERT INTO statement.  String literals can span multiple lines:

```
declare @t table (d varchar(10))
insert into @t values ('a
b
c')
```

Answer (score 2):

We have had the same issue.

You can either use and insert statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (Col1,..., Coln)
SELECT  Val1,...,
'MULTILINE
VALUE',...,Valn
```

Or use Access with linked tables to insert the values with multi lines.